# Single Login Entry for Shinymanager

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am currently using the shinymanager package for authentication for my shiny app, but it looks like multiple users can log in if they use the same credentials. i.e. two people using the same username and password on two separate machines.

Is there a way to deny access to a user if they are already logged in elsewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: How about removing the logged credentials after a successful logging? Obviously, you need to then return the credentials after the session is over.